# converting byte array into hexadecimal string with delimiter? Removing last character displayed in a string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character-encoding

I am working on a program that will convert a byte array of lets say {13,13,12,12,4,4,4,4} to 13d:12c:44:44 , (1-15 in decimal)(1-15 in hexadecimal) : and on to the next two digits. My code below works and prints out what I want except that it always include a : at the end. So instead of (13d:12c:44:44), the output is (13d:12c:44:44:). I tried playing with an else if statement with two conditions but it does not work if any digits are consecutive. The else if condition I included prints (13d:12c:4444) instead.

```
public static void main(String []args){

    byte [] pracArray = {13,13,12,12,4,4,4,4};

    for ( int i = 0; i < pracArray.length; i+=2)
    {
        if ( pracArray[i] == 0) { System.out.print("0");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 1) { System.out.print("1");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 2) { System.out.print("2");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 3) { System.out.print("3");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 4) { System.out.print("4");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 5) { System.out.print("5");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 6) { System.out.print("6");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 7) { System.out.print("7");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 8) { System.out.print("8");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 9) { System.out.print("9");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 10) { System.out.print("10");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 11) { System.out.print("11");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 12) { System.out.print("12");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 13) { System.out.print("13");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 14) { System.out.print("14");}
        if ( pracArray[i] == 15) { System.out.print("15");}

        if( pracArray[i+1] == 0) {System.out.print("0:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 1) {System.out.print("1");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 2) {System.out.print("2:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 3) {System.out.print("3:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 4 && pracArray[pracArray.length-1] == 4) {System.out.print("4");}
        else if( pracArray[i+1] == 4)  {System.out.print("4:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 5) {System.out.print("5:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 6) {System.out.print("6:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 7) {System.out.print("7:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 8) {System.out.print("8:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 9) {System.out.print("9:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 10) {System.out.print("a:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 11) {System.out.print("b:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 12) {System.out.print("c:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 13) {System.out.print("d:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 14) {System.out.print("e:");}
        if( pracArray[i+1] == 15) {System.out.print("f:");}


}
```

}

Would appreciate any help on my how to fix my code when repeating digits are found or a way with less code as I am a beginner. Is there a way to simply not display the last character in a string? That way I think my original code will work as the final character will always be a : and it wont be printed.

Comment: 13,13 becoming 13c is exactly why I tried to tell you that a byte need two hex digits. What if it was c13? How could you tell?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch it will never be c13. The first value should be displayed in decimal and the second value should be displayed in hexadecimal.  Here are my specific instructions                  
                                                                                                                 
Translates RLE data into a human-readable representation. For each run, in order, it should display the run
length in decimal (1-2 digits); the run value in hexadecimal (1 digit); and a delimiter, ‘:’, between runs. 
Ex: (new byte[] { 15, 15, 6, 4 }) yields string "15f:64".

Comment: @ElliotFrish if I am able to either not display the last character in my output string, or remove : from the last iteration entirely, it would solve my problem. But I understand that is due to how I approached it

Comment: Not certain if this is homework or not but are you familiar with loops?

Comment: @WJS It is part of a larger encoding project I am working on for school. I am pretty new to loops and java in general. Would a nested for loop be something I do here instead? My output is my intended output except for the final :

Comment: Iteration (using loops in programming) is made for situations like this.  You would use a for loop, indexed by 2 and grab the character for a proper hexadecimal nibble ( 4 bits or 0-9 and A-F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to assist by not spoonfeeding you the answer since that is frowned upon on this site.  So much for that.  So here is how you should do it.

```
        int[] nums= {13,13,12,12,4,4,4,4};
        String syms = "0123456789ABCDEF";

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i+=2) {
           // Use String.charAt() for getting Hex token
           System.out.print(nums[i]+"" + syms.charAt(nums[i+1]));
           if (i < nums.length-2) {
               // decide when to print ending colon.
               System.out.print(":");
           }
        }
```

Comment: always interesting to see my long lines of beginner code shortened so much. i have alot to learn. I have question on how String syms = "0123456789ABCDEF", comes into play tho. Why does syms.charAt(nums[i+1] print the second value I need. Lets say for 13,13. Is it going down the string and then printing (13) which it has 'c'.?

Comment: Let's say `num = 13` which is  `D` in hex.  The character in the string at index `13` is `D` and that is what `syms.charAt()` does.  It provides the character at that particular index in the string.

Comment: Instead of `syms.charAt(nums[i+1])` you could use `Integer.toHexString(nums[i + 1])` - but that will be in lowercase letters (if it matters).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If one wanted upper case they could just append a `.toUpperCase()` call.

Answer (score 1):

You are using way too many if statements, but before I get on to that, let's fix your code.

Your code can be fixed by not printing the colons in the if statements, but putting an if statements at the end, that checks whether it is the last iteration of the loop, and only prints the colon if it is *not*.

```
// no colons here!
if( pracArray[i+1] == 0) {System.out.print("0");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 1) {System.out.print("1");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 2) {System.out.print("2");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 3) {System.out.print("3");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 4) {System.out.print("4");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 5) {System.out.print("5");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 6) {System.out.print("6");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 7) {System.out.print("7");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 8) {System.out.print("8");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 9) {System.out.print("9");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 10) {System.out.print("a");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 11) {System.out.print("b");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 12) {System.out.print("c");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 13) {System.out.print("d");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 14) {System.out.print("e");}
if( pracArray[i+1] == 15) {System.out.print("f");}

// if last iteration of loop, print colon
if (i + 1 != pracArray.length - 1) {
    System.out.print(":");
}
```

Now let's shorten your code :)

```
for ( int i = 0; i < pracArray.length; i+=2)
{
    // for the elements at even indices, you just print them out directly, no need for conversion or anything
    // so all your if statements are unnecessary
    System.out.print(pracArray[i]);

    // then it's the odd indices. If it's less than 10, handle them the same way
    if (pracArray[i + 1] < 10) {
        System.out.print(pracArray[i + 1]);
    } else {
        // but if it's >= 10, convert it to hex.
        System.out.print((char)('a' + pracArray[i + 1] - 10));
    }
    if (i + 1 != pracArray.length - 1) {
        System.out.print(":");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to help this person by giving suggestions.  Do you really think that I or especially Elliot Frisch could not have supplied the answer?

Comment: @WJS What's your point? I don't think this is a question that doesn't deserve to be answered. Quoting the close reasons here: it isn't off topic, nor does it need more focus or clarity, nor is opinion based. If you can find a duplicate, please do.

Comment: appreciate the help from everyone